Is there anyway I can send spl tokens despite this congestion?
I am trying to send spl tokens and make it consistent despite this congestion. I've been getting 2 successful transactions in 50 tries even though I am using a function from Jupiter that forcefully sends transactions multiple times.
I have seen the likes of Phantom wallet sending SPL tokens without failing. So, I believe it is possible. I have upped the retries to 100,000 even. It still didn't guarantee consistency. Is there any suggestion?
Here is my code
const {
    Connection,
    Keypair,
    VersionedTransaction,
    PublicKey,
    TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError,
    VersionedTransactionResponse,
    Transaction
  } = require("@solana/web3.js");
  const {
    createTransferInstruction,
    getAssociatedTokenAddress,
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount
  } = require('@solana/spl-token');
  const fetch = require("cross-fetch");
  const { Wallet } = require("@project-serum/anchor");
  const bs58 = require("bs58");
  const promiseRetry = require("promise-retry");
   

  async function getWallet(privateKeys) {
    return new Wallet(Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs58.decode(privateKeys)))
  }

  const QUICKNODE_RPC ="https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/";


  const connection = new Connection(QUICKNODE_RPC, "confirmed");


  const wait = (time) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  
  async function transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter({
    connection,
    serializedTransaction,
    blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight,
  }) {
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
      serializedTransaction,
      { skipPreflight: true }
    );
  
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const abortSignal = controller.signal;
  
    const abortableResender = async () => {
      while (true) {
        await wait(2_000);
        if (abortSignal.aborted) return;
        try {
          await connection.sendRawTransaction(
            serializedTransaction,
            { skipPreflight: true }
          );
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(`Failed to resend transaction: ${e}`);
        }
      }
    };
  
    try {
      abortableResender();
      const lastValidBlockHeight =
        blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight.lastValidBlockHeight - 150;
  
      await Promise.race([
        connection.confirmTransaction(
          {
            ...blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight,
            lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature: txid,
            abortSignal,
          },
          "confirmed"
        ),
        new Promise(async (resolve) => {
          while (!abortSignal.aborted) {
            await wait(2_000);
            const tx = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {
              searchTransactionHistory: false,
            });
            if (tx?.value?.confirmationStatus === "confirmed") {
              resolve(tx);
            }
          }
        }),
      ]);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError) {
        console.log("TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError")
        return null;
      } else {
        throw e;
      }
    } finally {
      controller.abort();
    }
  
    const response = promiseRetry(
      async (retry) => {
        const response = await connection.getTransaction(txid, {
          commitment: "confirmed",
          maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
        });
        if (!response) {
          retry(response);
        }
        return response;
      },
      {
        retries: 100000,
        minTimeout: 1e3,
      }
    );
  
    return response;
  }


const sendSplTokenWithBase58 = async (
    privateKeyBase58,
    toKeyBase58,
    numOfToken,
    tokenAddress,
    connection,
    decimal = 6
) => {
    try {
        console.log("started");
        const privateKey = bs58.decode(privateKeyBase58);
        const fromKeyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKey);
        const mintAddress = new PublicKey(tokenAddress);

        const tokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            fromKeyPair,
            mintAddress,
            fromKeyPair.publicKey,
        );

        const destinationAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            fromKeyPair,
            mintAddress,
            new PublicKey(toKeyBase58),
        );

        const transaction = new Transaction({ feePayer: fromKeyPair.publicKey })
            .add(
                createTransferInstruction(
                    tokenAccount.address,
                    destinationAccount.address,
                    fromKeyPair.publicKey,
                    numOfToken * Math.pow(10, decimal),
                ),
            );

        const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("confirmed");
        transaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockHash.blockhash;

        // Sign the transaction
        transaction.sign(fromKeyPair);

        // Serialize the transaction
        const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize();

        // Get blockhash with expiry block height
        const blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight = {
            blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
            lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight
        };

        // Send and confirm the transaction using the new function
        const transactionResponse = await transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter({
            connection,
            serializedTransaction,
            blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight,
        });

        // Extract relevant information from the transaction response
        const transactionHash = transactionResponse?.transaction?.signatures[0].toBase58();
        const transactionStatus = transactionResponse ? true : false;
        const splTokensSent = numOfToken;

        console.log({ transactionHash, transactionStatus, splTokensSent });
        return { transactionHash, transactionStatus, splTokensSent };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        return { transactionHash: false };
    }
};

The original example from the transaction sender here https://github.com/jup-ag/jupiter-quote-api-node/blob/main/example/utils/transactionSender.ts uses 5 retries. I have tampered with it and tried 50, 1000, 10000, 100000. Everytime, very few transaction goes through and others fail
I also tried increasing compute fee by tampering with this part.
 const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
        serializedTransaction,
        { skipPreflight: true, maxRetries: 5, priorityFeePerComputeUnit: 25000 } // Increased fee and added maxRetries
    );

Can anyone help me?
